# Odd Tkinter mouse-over behavior

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been trying to get a mouse-over event to change the background color of a butten widget in Tkinter. I got some simple code online which works for text, but fails for color. Here it is:

```
from Tkinter import *
root - Tk()

b = Button(root, text='foo')
b.pack()

def enterB(event):
    b.configure(text='bar', background='red')

def leaveB(event):
    b.configure(text='foo')

b.bind('<Enter>', enterB)
b.bind('<Leave>', leaveB)

root.mainloop()
```

When I put my mouse over the button, the text changes to 'bar', but the background color stays gray. When my mouse leaves the area over the button, the background color changes to red, and the text changes to 'foo'. This is the opposite of what should happen.

If I put background='blue' in the b.configure statement in the leaveB function, and leave the rest the same, leaving the button will leave the button blue, and it will never be red.

Can anyone tell me what's happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Good question. I don't want to offend you, but you should think if you really want to learn an UI toolkit that has been there for mere tradition (source: http://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter, maybe you can find some helpful resources there as well).

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure I get you. Are you saying that there is no reason to use Tkinter apart from a nice journey into python history? That it's not useful? Thanks for the link. I use that page frequently.

Comment: *In my opinion* Tkinter is a little old-fashioned, only easy to program on first sight (as you have expierenced) and last but not least it looks not to good. There are contenders like [`wxPython`](http://wxpython.org/), [`PyQt`](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt) and [`PyGTK`](https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) which have recent development, bug fixes, documentation, native look&feel and are more powerful. I recommend `wxPython`. The only drawback with these UI toolkits is that they aren't distributed with the Python interpreter, you've to install them manually.

Comment: Personally I think tkinter is a fantastic choice for learning GUI programming. Not only that, it's a fantastic choice for most GUI tasks. I wouldn't recommend it for most commercial applications, but does quite well at many types of tasks. If you're really concerned about the look of tkinter apps, consider using the styled (ttk) widgets available in newer versions of tkinter (starting with 2.6, I believe)

Comment: I assume you are on a Mac.  If so, buttons are funky with tk.  You can't change the background color or relief style.  Use another UI toolkit if you want complex buttons.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, I guess that's a typo on line 2, it should be `root = Tk()`

---

That program works properly for me, other than the act that on removing the mouse from the button the background stays `red`. Which can be changed by slightly modifying `leaveB` function as follows:

```
def leaveB(event):
    b.configure(text="foo", background="SystemButtonFace")
```

Where `"SystemButtonFace"` is the default button face color if you are on Windows

Comment: Yes, you're correct, that's a typo. I do that one quite frequently :-( I'll try out your solution and get back to you later on today.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem (actually I was bothered with the button color not changing after a click unless you left it with the mouse). The solution was to set the activebackground color. In my understanding this is the color which is shown when the mouse is over the button (see http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_button.htm)

So what I did was:

```
def enterB(event):
   b.configure(text='bar', background='red')
   b.configure(activebackground='red');
```

This way the button already turns red when the mouse is over it. Of course you have to reset the color in the leaveB function to make it change back to grey once you left the button.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a Mac, you can't change the background color or relief style of a button.  You can change the highlightbackground color, however.  This is a limitation of tk on macs, thus I would recommend wx instead.